# Compare new line

Tags: c#, compare

How can compare new line in textbox multiple line same below :-

```
if(textbox1.text[i]== '\')
```

note : new line == \r   in textbox

I try compare with ascii code .. but not work

Comment: Would you mind to provide class names, proper tag (WinForms/WPF/WebForms) and compilable sample? I assume you are not using WinForms as `TextBox` already have [Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property that likely does what you looking for...

Comment: Side note: "not work" is generally considered as incomplete explanation for SO questions. Please try to provide more detailed information for your questions (usually complete compile or run-time error message describes problem much better).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the escape character,

```
if (textbox1.text[i]== '\r')
```

Although, this may vary system to system, so you should check for `'\n'`, or try `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Note that `Environment.NewLine` can't be used to check single character as it often 2 characters...

Comment: Your right, if `\r` or `\n` does not work for OP they need to check for each character after each other if `Environment.NewLine.Length > 1`

Comment: true ,, i try your answer and came true